# Failing to parse 1 MB XML File with BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have two SVG maps of the world, downloaded [here](https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=world). My goal is to do some editing of these maps in python, working with them via BeautifulSoup4. This works perfectly with the low-res file (132.5 Kb). However, the BS4 parser (using lxml) fails entirely when I attempt to use it with the high-res file (1.2 Mb).

The code is as such:

```
    import lxml
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    with open('worldHigh.svg','r') as f:
        handler = f.read()
        soup = Soup(handler,'xml')
        print(soup.prettify())
```

When I run that with the worldHigh.svg fifle, the only thing that is printed is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

When I run the equivalent, but changing worldHigh.svg for worldLow.svg, it prints the XML correctly (as desired).

Both SVG files work fine when opened by themselves (i.e., they show the map). However, one fails when I try to parse it, the other succeeds. I am at a loss for what is going wrong. I would understand if the parser fails at large sizes, but 1.2 MB does not seem large.

Comment: Try `with open('worldHigh.svg','rb') as f:`. If it works, I'll add an explanation why, later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML parser needs the raw sequence of unencoded bytes. Use `open(...,'rb')` when parsing XML.

The reason why one worked and the other didn't is `worldHigh.svg` has a BOM at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Oh, you glorious and amazing human being. It does now load, and the prettify() prints properly. However, the SVG file doesn't work entirely, it now fails wherever there is a special character (e.g. line 61, title="Côte d'Ivoire" or line 70, title="Curaçao"). It works if I remove the special characters, which I can do -- but oddly, they're present in the low-res map which works fine. Happy to rest here, and I am extremely thankful, but if there's a quick fix you know of for this I'd love it too.

Comment: In my download of `worldHigh.svg`, I get different line numbers. I suspect that you have edited your copy. Try again with a fresh download.

Comment: Re-downloaded, and made a simple script that reads (as above), then prints to a new file.
`with open('pyParsedWorldHigh.svg','w+') as f:
     f.write(soup.prettify())
` (including the necessary line break).
Indeed the line numbers are different by one, but it still results in an error.

Comment: That is a separate error, worthy of its own question, but the solution might be: `with open('pyParsedWorldHigh.svg','w', encoding="utf8") as f: f.write(soup.prettify())` @RobertRedelmeier

Comment: I'll check it out, but definitely not vital. Thanks again for all your help, it was really generous and deeply deeply appreciated.